# Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder even though StaticLoggerBinder is in Maven-Rep

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

I'm trying to use the slf4j-Logger-Functions but always getting the same error:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for
>   further details.

I already tried the common solutions and as you can see in the image, the "StaticLoggerBinder" is loaded into the directory but the error still excists. Do you have any idea why?

```java
package de.stefan.test;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);
        logger.info("This is how you configure Java Logging with SLF4J");
    }
}
```

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.stefan</groupId>
    <artifactId>stefan</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkM4H.png)

Comment: I have no idea - but if this is related to tess4j - Get over It! Use something else create your Own Files!!!

Comment: Check if https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/slf4j/solving-failed-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error/ this is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slf4j-simple` is not your classpath when you ran the program. Put it in your classpath, something like `java -classpath ./lib/* YourProgram`. Where **lib** contains your jar files.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have following 4j dependencies in pom, and add log4j.properties/xml with required appanders i.e. for Console or/and file in your class path .

1. Mention the the version in properties as per your needs, recent is better-

   <log4j.version>2.13.3</log4j.version>

```html
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

2. A sample Log4j Config Properties file can be like this-

```html
 status = error
name= properties_configuration

# Give directory path where log files should get stored
#property.basePath = E:\\AppTest_logs\\

# ConsoleAppender will print logs on console
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = STDOUT
appender.file.filename = logs/AppsConsole.log
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.console.filter.threshold.level = error

# Specify the pattern of the logs
appender.console.layout.pattern = %highlight{ [%p] %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %x %c %M - %m%n}{FATAL=white, ERROR=Blink red, WARN=Underline yellow, INFO=Bright white, DEBUG=Bright green, TRACE=blue}
appender.file.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%t-%x-%-5p-%-10c:%m%n

# RollingFileAppender will print logs in file which can be rotated based on time or size


# Mention package name here in place of example. Classes in this package or subpackages will use ConsoleAppender and RollingFileAppender for logging
logger.example.name = com.threeylos.zapizook
logger.example.level = info
logger.example.additivity = false
logger.example.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
logger.example.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleLogger

# Configure root logger for logging error logs in classes which are in package other than above specified package

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.additivity = false
#rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleLogger
```